# union of All Parent in multilevel or tree structure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table

```
1. parent table and 2. Child Table
```

Parent Table value

```
Pid parent_name
1  A 
2  B
3  D
4  H
5  J
```

Child Table Value

```
Chid Pid child_name
1     1   B
2     1   C
3     1   D
4     2   F
5     2   G
6     3   H
7     3   I
8     4   J
9     4   K
10    5   L
```

when I give input A then i will get output as

```
Pid
B
D
H
J
```

when I give input D then i will get output as

```
Pid
H
J
```

Is like tree structure when i give parent name then result will be all child ,grandchild ,grand child child....
all parent which have child

Answer (score 0):

You need to use recursive CTE for your purpose.

```
 DECLARE @Id varchar(10)='your_pid' 
;WITH cte AS 
 (
  SELECT b.pid, b.chid, b.parent_name
  FROM parent a inner join child b on b.pid= a.pid
  WHERE b.pid = @Id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT b.pid
  FROM parent a inner join child b on b.pid= a.pid
  inner join cte on cte.pid= b.chid
  WHERE b.pid = @Id  )
  SELECT parent_name
  FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to store the parent child records in a single table as follows:

```
1   NULL    A
2   1   B
3   1   C
4   1   D
5   2   F
6   2   G
7   4   H
8   4   I
9   7   J
10  7   K
11  9   L
```

Then you can query the data as follows:

```
WITH T (id, pid, name) AS (
    SELECT 1, NULL, 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 1, 'B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 1, 'C'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 1, 'D'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 2, 'F'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 2, 'G'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 4, 'H'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 4, 'I'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 7, 'J'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 7, 'K'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 9, 'L'
), U AS (
    SELECT B.* FROM T A JOIN T B ON B.pid = A.id JOIN T C ON C.pid = B.id WHERE A.name = 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT P.* FROM T P JOIN U Q ON Q.id = P.pid JOIN T R ON R.pid = P.id
)
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM U
```

For example, if your table is named "tbl" then:

```
WITH T (id, pid, name) AS (
    SELECT id, pid, name FROM tbl
), U AS (
    SELECT B.* FROM T A JOIN T B ON B.pid = A.id JOIN T C ON C.pid = B.id WHERE A.name = 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT P.* FROM T P JOIN U Q ON Q.id = P.pid JOIN T R ON R.pid = P.id
)
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM U
```